# MySQL Select distinct row where one column is identical, and 2nd column is "3" or "4"

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data that looks something like this:

```
    +------+--------+------------+
    | id   | Action | GeoDataID  |
    +------+--------+------------+
    | 1    | 3      | 117085664  |
    | 2    | 4      | 117085664  |
    | 3    | 3      | 117096940  |
    | 4    | 3      | 117096404  |
    +------+--------+------------+
```

Now, I want to get all GeoDataID's that only has action = 3, and not action = 4. PS!! 1 and 2 have IDENTICAL GeoDataID and should not return row 1 in the result. 
As you can see from id 1 and 2 they have identical GeoDataID.

From this example I want output only id 3 and 4. I've been trying to google, but can't find anything similar to what I want.

From the example above, the result should be:

```
+------+--------+------------+
| id   | Action | GeoDataID  |
+------+--------+------------+
| 3    | 3      | 117096940  |
| 4    | 3      | 117096404  |
+------+--------+------------+
```

1 and 2 not included due to  GeoDataID 117085664  having Action 4.

Comment: Come on. Try *something*

Comment: Sounds as easy as a WHERE clause, e.g. `SELECT id, Action, GeoDataID FROM MyTable WHERE Action = 3`. What are we missing? Do you mean all rows except those which have duplicates (in which case exclude both rows?)

Comment: what is wrong 

`SELECT t.GeoDataID
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.Action = 3`

Should make it , at least give a snippet of code that fails

Comment: `SELECT id
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Action=3 AND id in (3,4)`

Comment: Thanks for replies, but read before replying please, if I only wanted all rows with 3 I would simply have selected them.

WHat I want is all rows with action = 3, that doesnt have an identical row with action = 4.

Begueradj, I don't know the ID's of the rows I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the items which have the same GeoDataID but Action 4 by introducing the 'negative criteria' with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT mt1.id, mt1.Action, mt1.GeoDataID 
FROM MyTable mt1
WHERE mt1.Action = 3
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM MyTable mt2
   WHERE mt2.Action = 4
         AND mt2.GeoDataID = mt1.GeoDataID
);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c50f/1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this did excactly what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow! - as per the comments,  you'll find folk more helpful if you show what you've tried, no matter how far off the mark it is (Your update to the original question makes all the difference in showing us what you were after). The [question FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are here